# Get record id from looped records

Tags: mysql

Here is the story

i have two mysql tables like :

**master**

```
id, descr
1, master 1
2, master 2
```

**details**

```
id, descr, masterid
1, test 1, 1
2, test 2, 1
3, test 3, 1
4, test 1, 2
5, test 2, 2
6, test 3, 2
```

I need a query to get the rows from the first table and a looped column from the details

For example :

first execute :

```
1,master 1, 1

2,master 2, 4
```

second execute

```
1,master 1, 2<- From the details table

2,master 2, 5<- From the details table
```

third execute

```
1,master 1, 3<- From the details table

2,master 2, 6<- From the details table
```

Fourth execute :

```
1,master 1, 1

2,master 2, 4
```

I guess i have to add a column on master table to keep the last selected record from the details table but i can't design the query.

Any ideas?

Thank you
Vangelis

Comment: can you not do this in a different programming language?

Comment: I can combine mysql and php.. I am trying for the best solution

Comment: best solution would be to do this in php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is - you can do it with SQL only. But that will be **session-related**. By that, I mean this query:

```
SELECT
  master.*,
  o.id AS oid
FROM
  master
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
      d.*,
      @num:=IF(@id=masterid, @num:=@num+1, 1) AS num,
      @id:=masterid
    FROM
      (SELECT * FROM details ORDER BY masterid) AS d
      CROSS JOIN 
       (SELECT @id:=0, @num:=0) AS init
     ) AS o
    ON master.id=o.masterid
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
       masterid,
       COUNT(id) AS c 
     FROM 
       details 
     GROUP BY 
       masterid) AS counts
    ON master.id=counts.masterid
    CROSS JOIN 
      (SELECT @RUN_COUNT:=IF(@RUN_COUNT IS NULL, 1, @RUN_COUNT+1)) AS r
WHERE
  o.num=IF(!(@RUN_COUNT%(counts.c)), counts.c, @RUN_COUNT%(counts.c));
```

Very important detail of it is `@RUN_COUNT`. It will be looped only in terms of **one session**. That is: if you'll start another session, then initializing of this variable will happen again:

```
(SELECT @RUN_COUNT:=IF(@RUN_COUNT IS NULL, 1, @RUN_COUNT+1)) AS r
```

-as you can see, this simply checks if it isn't initialized - and, if it's not, then it will initialize it. So, this **will fail** if you're acting in different sessions.

SQLFiddle behaves like *one* session, thus it's [working there](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22d104/7) (but you'll need first to set `@RUN_COUNT` to `NULL`, of course - because I've already run this query)

The query above will work if there are different counts for different master ids (like I've done in fiddle, 4 for `masterid=1` and 3 for `masterid=2`). But - again, you can not rely on `@RUN_COUNT` in common case. If your session isn't persistent between your application and your DBMS - then you'll have to handle it *in application*.

Comment: WOW! This is exactly what I need!

I can use an extra field on master table to keep @RUN_COUNT value using php there is no problem with that.

I can see one problem, using this data set 

(1, 'test 1', 1),
(2, 'test 2', 1),
(3, 'test 3', 1),
(4, 'test 4', 2),
(5, 'test 5', 2),
(6, 'test 6', 2);

I can't get the third query correct

Comment: No. You didn't get the sense of `@RUN_COUNT`. You _can not_ "keep" it. It corresponds for _what time is your query run_. That means - it may be valid _only inside session_. If you'll run this query in different sessions - it _will fail_ (and there will be no such thing as "run count" at all - it may exist only in context of one session). So if your PHP application will not maintain persistent connection, this will fail. And you'll better to do whole logic in PHP then. Also, I can't see problem with your data. Works fine for me

Comment: Ok got it about session. Using this dataset i am getting 1,4 - 2,5 and goes back to 1,4. Don't know why but I can't get 3,6 set

Comment: Very, very strange. I'm getting all values correctly, and (3,6) too (in correct sequence). Tested on my local mysql server session

Answer (score 0):

in reference to what I said earlier --- if you were to do it in php, this is the sql select you would want to do to get the data in the correct format.. from here you could do a loop inside a loop in php with a limit set to break at 2.. should probably do the trick

```
SELECT 
    m.id AS master_id, 
    m.descr, 
    d.id AS detail_id
FROM master m
JOIN details d ON d.masterid = m.id
```